# Using reduce on an object with an array

Tags: javascript, lodash, underscore.js, reduce

I have this JavaScript object

```
{ 
names: [ "youtube","twitch"],
autoEnable: true
}
```

I want to convert this object into an array of objects for every name I have in my array. autoEnable and isEnabled correspond

```
[{
  name: youtube,
  isEnabled: true
},
{
  name: twitch,
  isEnabled: true
}]
```

Comment: What is keeping you from doing this?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a use case for [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) (outside of functional programming with prebuilt, reusable reducers, almost nothing is, though it's often used anyway); it's a case for [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```
const obj = { 
    names: [ "youtube","twitch"],
    autoEnable: true
};
const array = obj.names.map(name => ({name, views: 46, isEnabled: obj.autoEnable}));
```

Live Example:

```js
const obj = { 
    names: [ "youtube","twitch"],
    autoEnable: true
};
const array = obj.names.map(name => ({name, views: 46, isEnabled: obj.autoEnable}));
console.log(array);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const data = { 
names: [ "youtube","twitch"],
autoEnable: true
}

const a = data.names.map((name) => {
  return {
    name,
    isEnabled: true, // you could run a function here to get this value
    views: 46 // you could run a function here to get this value
  }
});

console.log(a);
```